# ¿Cómo traducir al español la expresión inglesa "Being rammed through"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-modismo

Por ejemplo:

> Wales Bill being rammed through Parliament, says academic.

Comment: Hola Alice, ¿qué se te ocurre a ti? Es importante ofrecer tu propuesta al preguntar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En España se utiliza la palabra *rodillo* (o *rodillo parlamentario*) para expresar la práctica de aprobar leyes en el parlamento cuando el partido del gobierno tiene mayoría absoluta y no necesita acordarlas con nadie más. Pero no tenemos un verbo para ello, simplemente usamos la expresión *usar el rodillo*, así que las frases se construyen de manera diferente. Por ejemplo:

> El rodillo parlamentario aprobó el Acta de Gales

Otros ejemplos:

> El gobierno ha usado su rodillo para aprobar más de 140 leyes en un año.
>
> Se ha acusado al partido gobernante de abusar del rodillo en lugar de alcanzar pactos con la oposición.

Este uso se ha popularizado tanto que incluso ha llegado al diccionario de la RAE, sexta acepción de la palabra *rodillo*:

> 6. m. En una institución cuyas decisiones se adoptan mediante votos, uso resolutivo de la mayoría de la que se dispone, sin atender a las
>    razones de la minoría.

Comment: O _pasar el rodillo_

Comment: Here in Argentina we use the expression *usar el Congreso/la Legislatura como una escribanía*. Just as a notary will certify anything that he is asked by his client to sign, so will the official or government party representatives sign anything the executive asks them to set their signatures to.

Comment: En Chile sería _la aplanadora_.

Comment: @Rodrigo, ¿quieres decir que en Chile usáis *aplanadora* con este sentido o que es en general la palabra que usáis en lugar de *rodillo* en otros casos? Si es esto último, creo que el equivalente a *aplanadora* en España es *apisonadora*, aunque alguna vez he oído usar *aplanadora* también. El rodillo es exclusivamente el cilindro giratorio.

Comment: Es tanto la maquinota que empareja caminos como la acción de legislar a la rápida, aprovechando que hay mayoría (sobre todo para anular lo que ha hecho el otro bando).

Comment: Ajá. Es una idea parecida a la que utilizamos en España, entonces. Aquí utilizamos al expresión *entrar como una apisonadora* para expresar la idea de entrar en un sitio nuevo, tal vez una organización, y hacer grandes cambios. Por ejemplo, podemos decir que Trump ha entrado como una apisonadora en el gobierno de Estados Unidos. Pero no se aplica solo a política; por ejemplo, un nuevo entrenador puede entrar como una apisonadora en un equipo y cambiar toda la alineación del mismo.

Answer (score 2):

Yo no conozco la política de Gales y Gran Bretaña, pero conozco el modismo "ram through," y propondría

> **imponer sin debate** (es decir, sin dar oportunidad de discusión, o sin consultar a todos los sectores políticos)

Mi argumento: la definición de *ram something through* es, según [thefreedictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ram+through), es

> 2 - to force something through a deliberative body, usually not allowing due consideration [forzar algo por un órgano de deliberación, tipicamente sin permitir la consideración debida]. *They rammed the bill through the city council. The President was unable to ram the measure through Congress.*